# c# converting string into date time

Tags: c#, datetime

I have string like this "24:00:00" and I would like to convert it to time. I tried convert and DateTime.Parse but it seems like it needs a date too. Is there a way to just get time, or do I have to put in a date as well?

Comment: FYI, 24 hour time goes from 0:00:00 to 23:59:59 and 24:00:00 would be invalid.

Comment: Take a look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253270/c-how-to-convert-string-into-time-format-used-for-time-range

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are only interested in the time component, consider using `TimeSpan` instead of the full `DateTime`.

```
var time = TimeSpan.Parse("23:59:59");
```

Comment: I know there are some strange date formats... but having a month in the middle of a time is a new one for me ;-)

Comment: Doh! I got my month and minute mixed up! removed it anyway before you told me.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure "24:00:00" is going to be a valid time. Any how, you should not need to specify the date, you can do...

```
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact("23:59:59", "HH:mm:ss", null);
```

If your time is actually a time of the day, then I would suggest sticking with DateTime. If you are actually using an amount of time (i.e. can be more that 23:59:59) then you could use TimeSpan...

```
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.ParseExact("23:59:59", "HH:mm:ss", null);
```

don't forget, both have a TryParseExact version if you are not sure you input will be valid

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DateTimeFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx) to format your DateTime.

```
string strDate = "23:10:00";
DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
dtfi.ShortTimePattern = "hh:mm:ss";
dtfi.TimeSeparator = ":";
DateTime objDate = Convert.ToDateTime(strDate, dtfi);
Console.WriteLine(objDate.TimeOfDay.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `TimeSpan.Parse` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use timespan

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
var time = new DateTime.Today;
var str = "24:00:00";
var split = str.split(":");

time.AddHours(Convert.ToInt32(split[0]));
time.AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(split[1]));
time.AddSeconds(Convert.ToInt32(split[2]));
```

Hope this helps.